# Unable to move text within a div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to give the date a margin of 15px between the bottom of the header and the text itself, but it doesn't move no matter what I tried.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
    <script src="myscripts.js"></script>
    <title>The Impertus · Understand the News</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="Preheader">
        <img src="images/masthead.png">
        <div class ="ph" id="hd"></div>
        <p class="ph">May 14, 2016</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald');

html, body {
    background-color: #E1D4C0;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

.ph {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#Preheader {
    height: 150px;
    width:100%;
    background-color: #104386;
    font-family: Oswald;
    color: #F5EDE3;
}
```

Created Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/fhkh6ae0/

Comment: create a fiddle please so that we can help you more

Comment: Created here: https://jsfiddle.net/fhkh6ae0/1/

Answer (score 1):

Add `.ph { vertical-align:15px; }`

See https://jsfiddle.net/fhkh6ae0/2/

Comment: Your inline level elements; text contents' were locked to being on the baseline. No margin or padding would change that. Using vertical-align with a length value moves the elements relative to that baseline.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.ph {
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a padding in `#Preheader` and it will be okay. take a look https://jsfiddle.net/fhkh6ae0/3/

```css
#Preheader {
    height: 150px;
    width:100%;
    background-color: #104386;
    font-family: Oswald;
    color: #F5EDE3;
  padding-bottom:15px; /*added*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue lies in your html elements display property.

I see you are using this for the **.ph** class:

```
display: inline-block;
```

In order for your elements to align next to each other, but I think what you are trying to achieve here is possible by applying a float to your **#hd** and **.ph** elements:

```
float: left;
```

Here is some detailed information on **[CSS Floats](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/)** by CSS-Tricks. The method you are using can be a good thing to do in a lot of specific situations, but for your specific case, I think this is the right path to take.

### Here is a [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/r9384fzx/2/) for you.

You can see I changed some things and I added new things. One is the float property I am referencing above, and I have added an `overflow: hidden` property to the main container `#Preheader` , this is a fix for floating elements that try to escape their position or break your layout in bits. Remember the last one.